# Why is my Java program to merge 2 integer arrays only giving correct output to a certain point?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, merge

I have these 2 arrays:

array **A** [-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
array **B** [-33, -22, -11, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88]

As you can see, array **A** and array **B** are both sorted. I have to merge them into a third array (array **C**) which should be sorted. (I can't use any array sort function though)

Here is my while loop:

```
 int[] c = new int[a.length + b.length];
   int aCount = 0;
   int bCount = 0;
   int cIndex = 0;

   while (aCount < a.length && bCount < b.length) {
      if (a[aCount] < b[bCount]) {
         c[cIndex] = a[aCount];
         cIndex++;
         aCount++;
      }
      else {
         c[cIndex] = b[bCount];
         cIndex++;
         bCount++;
      }
   }
```

And this is my output:

[-33, -22, -11, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

It is working correctly until it reaches 11, but then after that it only displays 0's when it should be 44,55,66,77,88.

What am I missing?

Comment: `aCount` reaches `a.length` and the loop ends. Change the `&&` to `||`.

Comment: @Bubletan this won't help, it'll just result in an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` as soon as you reach the end of one of the two arrays

Comment: @Paul Oh yeah, true. Just copy the rest from the array which has not reached the end instead.

Comment: @Bubbletan how can I copy the rest of the array in Java?

Comment: @dinax Look at Paul's answer. Just add that code below yours.

Comment: Okay thanks. I see how he did it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop condition (`aCount < a.length && bCount < b.length`) becomes `false` as soon as **one** of the indices reaches the end of the array. Since you only increment one of the indices in the loop, that means there is at least 1 element in the other array that needs to be inserted to `c`.

You can add the following code to add the missing elements too:

```
// add elements missing from first array
while (aCount < a.length) {
     c[cIndex] = a[aCount];
     cIndex++;
     aCount++;
}

// add elements missing from second array
while (bCount < b.length) {
     c[cIndex] = b[bCount];
     cIndex++;
     bCount++;
}
```

Comment: @TheGuest Why not? One of the indices already equals the array length so no iterations of the while loop corresponding to that array will be executed. The other loop copies the remaining values of that array.

Answer (score 3):

You only merge the two arrays to the point, where you reach the end of array a. Afterwards the while loop breaks off. You'll have to insert the remaining values of the other array.

```
int[] tmp = (aCount == a.length ? b : a);
int ct = (aCount == a.length ? bCount : aCount);

for(; ct < tmp.length ; ct++)
     c[cIndex++] = temp[ct];
```

Answer (score 1):

After you pick each element from `a` and `b` you increment the respective index. When you get to the last element of `a` (namely `a[10]`) you increment the index again, and now `aCount` is no longer less than `a.length`. So you skip the entire rest of the process.

The zeros are the default value of `c` before values are set. Since you're not setting the values, they remain 0.